# I'm Getting error while trying to delete heap allocated int

Tags: c++, class, memory-management, runtime-error, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include <iostream>
class TEST
{
public:
    int* a = new int;
    TEST(int x)
        : a(&x)
    {

    }
    ~TEST()
    {
        delete a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        int i = 2;
        TEST T(i);
    }
    std::cin.get();
}
```

I tried to heap allocate integer in a TEST class and then delete it but
when I'm calling **delete a** in TEST class destructor I'm getting error in file called delete_scalar.cpp and I have no idea what does it mean and how to fix it. Where's the problem?

Comment: There is no reason to store a dynamic `int` like this, except as an exercise. Even then, you really should be using `std::unique_ptr` instead. Otherwise, you should include manual copy/move constructors and copy/move assignment operators, per the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), to avoid unwanted issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> TEST(int x)
>     : a(&x)
> {
>
> }
> ```

This code is causing *undefined behavior*. It is making `a` point at a local `int` that goes out of scope immediately afterwards, leaving `a` as a *dangling pointer* to invalid memory. `a` is never pointing at dynamic memory (the `new` expression in the declaration of `a` is ignored when `a` is initialized in the constructor's member initialization list). That is why the `delete` fails later.

To do what you are attempting, you need to either:

- move the `new` into the initialization list, eg:

```
int* a = nullptr;
    
TEST(int x)
    : a(new int(x))
{

}
```

- Or, if you want to keep using `new` in the declaration of `a`, then you can assign the value of that `int` from inside the constructor's body instead of in its initialization list, eg:

```
int* a = new int;
    
TEST(int x)
{
    *a = x;
}
```